# Не обновляется TextView подписанный на LiveData, после обновления значения во viewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, livedata

Не обновляется в основном фрагменте TextView tvCategory, когда меняю знаение в DialogFragment. В диалоге меняю значение, все теги во вьюМодел отчитываются о благополучном изменении, но в основном фрагменте текст не меняется. Если повернуть экран то тег в onCreateView отчитывается о старом значении (то есть изменений не видит).

TextView подписано на ливдату.

Подскажите плиз в чем причина?

In DialogFragment:

```
override fun onItemClick(category: String) {
    viewModel.sendCategory(category)
    dismiss()
}
```

In MainFragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding = FragmentEditTransacionBinding.bind(view)

    binding.apply {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: vm.categorySSH = ${viewModel.categorySSH}")
        layoutChooseCategory.setOnClickListener {
            CategoryDialog().show(parentFragmentManager, CategoryDialog.TAG)
        }

        viewModel.category.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            tvCategory.setText(it)
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: vm.category = $it")
        }
```

SharedViewModel:

```
class EditTransactionViewModel(
    private val state: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    var categorySSH = state.get<String>("category") ?: "Joy"
        set(value) {
            field = value
            state.set("category", value)
            Log.d(TAG, "sendCategory: LOGS categorySSH = $categorySSH")
        }

    val category = MutableLiveData(categorySSH)

    fun sendCategory(text: String) {
        categorySSH = text
        category.value = text
        Log.d(TAG, "sendCategory: LOGS categorySSH = $categorySSH")
        Log.d(TAG, "sendCategory: LOGS category.value = ${category.value}")
    }
```

Comment: можно использовать state.livedata вместо state.get и MutableLiveData(categorySSH), при установке значения в такую лайвдату она автоматически будет сохранять его в SavedStateHandle

Comment: Скорей всего у вас разные ViewModel в о фрагментах. Почему вы думаете, что она шарится? Как вы получаете ViewModel во фрагментах?

Comment: ```private val viewModel: EditTransactionViewModel by viewModels()``` - в обоих так получаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас создаются разные инстансы ViewModel

При показе фрагмента в другом фрагменте используйте `childFragmentManager`

```
CategoryDialog().show(childFragmentManager, CategoryDialog.TAG)
```

И если вы хотите получить в дочернем фрагменте ViewModel из родительского фрагмента, то используйте `by viewModels({ requireParentFragment() })` или `by activityViewModels()`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, это помогло.